# Do Christian Scientists believe that COVID-19 really is a virus?

Tags: covid-19, disease, christian-science

[Christian Scientists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Science) deny the Germ Theory, right? If so, how do they explain COVID-19?

Comment: Why wouldn't they? It based on science. **Christian Science** is not a scientific journal, but a publication as to what they believe.

Comment: @KenGraham Do you know what "Christian Science" is?

Comment: Please provide an authentic source from Christian Science to validate your claim that they deny germ theory.  You are supposed to show evidence of your own research before posting questions.  Clearly, you haven't done any.  So why should we?

Comment: @KenGraham, (citing Wikipedia), "adherents [...believe...] that reality is purely spiritual and the material world an illusion. This includes the view that disease is a mental error rather than physical disorder". Or, from our own tag, "it is best known for its teaching that all forms of illness are an illusion that can be overcome by prayer alone".

Comment: @FlatAssembler, Ken Graham's comment ((and mine), as all comments are supposed to be) was intended to help improve the question. Rather than replying to him in a comment, you should incorporate the additional information into the question itself. That would improve the question for everyone, especially after these comments eventually go away.

Comment: The title needs to be clarified. COVID-19 is a disease, not a virus. The virus involved with this disease is known as SARS‑CoV‑2. So taken literally, effectively no one believes that COVID-19 is a virus. Are you really asking "*… believe that COVID-19 is **caused** by a virus*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Facts:**  Germ theory, in medicine, is the theory that certain diseases are caused by the invasion of the body by microorganisms.  The term "germs" refers to microscopic bacteria, viruses, fungi, and protozoa that can cause disease.  There are four different categories of germs: bacteria, viruses, fungi and protozoa.  The coronavirus disease (COVID-19) is caused by a virus, not by bacteria.

As Matthew has pointed out in his comment (which is substantiated from the Wikipedia link he posted in the body of your question) ***Christian Science claims disease is a mental error.***  I found one external source that mentions Christian Science and the Covid-19 virus:

> The church doesn’t keep official numbers, but its membership has declined since 1936, when the U.S. Census reported nearly 270,000 members. Even so, Christian Science punches above its weight in the national consciousness. ***“No major religion opposes the COVID-19 vaccine,***” read a recent CNN explainer on religious exemptions, “***and that includes Christian Science, whose church members focus on prayer, not medicine, for healing.”***  https://www.tabletmag.com/sections/community/articles/christian-scientists-consider-covid-19-vaccinations

The claim that Christian Science does not oppose the COVID-19 vaccine may simply be a “cover-all” statement to suggest that the decision whether to have the vaccine or not is a matter of individual conscience.

***Christian Scientists identify matter-based thought as the cause of disease, and God-impelled thought as the cure.***  This is part of what they have said about the Covid-19 pandemic:

> In the Christian Science textbook, Mary Baker Eddy points out the underlying mental nature of disease when she writes about the need to exterminate “all the mental microbes of sin and all diseased thought-germs” (Science and Health with Key to the Scriptures, p. 164). Whether unintentionally or deliberately, we invite in “diseased thought-germs,” or error, by hosting fearful and sinful thoughts in our consciousness.

> ***Any pandemic, in order to have power over us, needs the individual’s consent.*** One’s tacit agreement with the majority opinion about a disease can determine the fear and the severity of the symptoms involved in the case. But ***yielding to divine Truth brings release*** from the multitude of popular gloom-and-doom assumptions, predictions, and opinions.....  As we increasingly become free from mortal or self-centered thinking, our bodies will be less susceptible to illness and disease, thanks to our growing understanding and love of God, who “healeth all [our] diseases” (Psalms 103:3).

> Mary Baker Eddy says on page 116 of Miscellany, “At a time of contagious disease, Christian Scientists endeavor to rise in consciousness to the true sense of the omnipotence of Life, Truth, and Love, and this great fact in Christian Science realized will stop a contagion.”
> https://sentinel.christianscience.com/shared/view/1ca1zp4znju

***You ask, Do Christian Scientists believe that COVID-19 really is a virus?***  This article, published in February 2021, suggests that Christian Science acknowledges that Covid-19 is a very real and dangerous virus:

> With the rollout of vaccines, we have entered a more hopeful phase in the fight against COVID-19. But how does one make sense of the labyrinth of 14-day averages, hospitalization rates, positivity percentages, and caseloads?  ... hospitalization rates indicate the toll that virus is taking on the community. As a subset of that data, the number of intensive care admissions underscores the strain that an outbreak is placing on medical capacity.

https://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2021/0201/Confused-by-pandemic-data-Here-s-some-help-reading-it